# Why does creating a color command in an HTML Terminal emulator create a (mostly) white screen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-terminal

I am making an HTML terminal, and have done most of the styling. I am trying to add one command, though, which will change the color. You can run these code snippets, and see why I'm asking this, but when you type in color and then a color, instead of doing what I'm trying to make it do, it just gives you a (mostly) white screen.

```js
$('body').terminal({
  iam: function(name) {
    this.echo('Hello, ' + name +
      '. Welcome to Coding Class!');
  },
  echo: function(what) {
    this.echo(what)
  },
  link: function(link) {
    window.location.replace("http://www." + link);
  },
  color: function(color) {
    var body = document.querySelector("body");
    body.className = "test";

    var temp = document.querySelectorAll(".test");

    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      temp[i].style.color = color;
      temp[i].style.fontSize = "40px";
    }
  }
}, {
  greetings: 'Hi!',
  prompt: 'root> '
})
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

Comment: 1. You overwrite all `body` class, not add. You should use add class instead.
2. You use stylesheet `color: xxx`. It is text color, not background color.

Comment: @vee could you maybe fit that into the code so I could see it? I am not the best at figuring things like that out lol

Answer (score 1):

To change the terminal's color in a more simple way you could also do:

```
color: function(clr) {
$("div, ul, li").css("background-color", clr);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$('body').terminal({
    iam: function(name) {
        this.echo('Hello, ' + name +
            '. Welcome to Coding Class!');
    },
    echo: function(what) {
        this.echo(what)
    },
    link: function(link) {
        window.location.replace("http://www." + link);
    },
    color: function(color) {
        var body = document.querySelector("body");
        body.classList.add('test');// add class name `test` to body.

        var temp = document.querySelectorAll(".test");

        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i].style.setProperty('--background', color);// use set variable instead of `background-color`.
            //temp[i].style.backgroundColor = color;// not recommended
            temp[i].style.fontSize = "40px";
        }
    }
}, {
    greetings: 'Hi!',
    prompt: 'root> '
})
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

I'm showing you how to use `add()` CSS class name to `body`.

To make background color change on command `color`, I change the code to use `setProperty()` to set CSS variable instead because the CSS file itself is already use that variable (in `.terminal` class) and it is easier this way.

Comment: OK thanks, this is really helpful!